# How can I use window.open in my string echo'd from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Through a $_POST request I query a database and return info in a string as follows:

```
$output .='<div class="searchdiv"> <b>'.$tit.' </b>- '.$art.' <br> <a href="#" onclick="window.open('.$prev.', "_blank", "width=600,height=350");" >preview tutorial</a> - <a href="'.$wat.'" target="blank">watch full tutorial</a></div>';
```

My problem is the "window.open" statement. It works as follows in a plain html doc as inline JS:

```
$output .='<div class="searchdiv"> <b>'.$tit.' </b>- '.$art.' <br> <a href="#" onclick="window.open('.$prev.', "_blank", "width=600,height=350");" >preview tutorial</a> - <a href="'.$wat.'" target="blank">watch full tutorial</a></div>';
```

But I think my problem in the PHP string is the single and double quotation marks.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the generated html in the browser and confirm if the html is well formed.

Comment: `onclick="window.open("'.$prev.'", "_blank", "width=600,height=350");"`

Comment: @DigitalDennis did my answer below help?

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around the URL.

```
$output .= '... <a href="#" onclick="window.open("' . $prev . '", "_blank", ...
// ---------------------------------------- here ^ -- and here ^
```

You would be able to notice this pretty quick if you looked at your HTML source, to see what was generated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've messed up the quotes in there slightly...

```
$output .='<div class="searchdiv"> <b>'.$tit.' </b>- '.$art.' <br> <a href="#" onclick="window.open('.$prev.', "_blank", "width=600,height=350");" >preview tutorial</a> - <a href="'.$wat.'" target="blank">watch full tutorial</a></div>';
```

You used `"` to define the onclick event, however you've used `"` inside of that event, which made it invalid. Replace the `"` inside of the event with `\'`, which will escape the quote and not mess up your PHP.

```
$output .='<div class="searchdiv"> <b>'.$tit.' </b>- '.$art.' <br> <a href="#" onclick="window.open('.$prev.', \'_blank\', \'width=600,height=350\');" >preview tutorial</a> - <a href="'.$wat.'" target="blank">watch full tutorial</a></div>';
```

And, if `$prev` is not referring to a variable in JS (if it will end up as a string), you need those quotes around that as well.

```
\''.$prev.'\'
```